# How to store an integer variable as an input in character array in Java?

Tags: java

Convert aaabbcc string to a string a3b2c2.Here is there any way to store integer value 3 in a character array.Can I convert aaabbcc string into a string a3b2c2.

Comment: Please add some description what you want .. you want to convert AAABBCC string into string A3B2C2 or in array of character??

Comment: Is a `String` or a `char[]`? And in any event, '3' is a character.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    String str = "aaabbcc";
    char c;
    ArrayList<String>count=new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if(!count.contains(str.charAt(i)+"")){
    count.add(str.charAt(i)+"");
    }
    }
```

int [] dd = new int [count.size()];

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    c=str.charAt(i);
       for(int j=0;j<count.size();j++){
           if(count.get(j).equals(c+"")){
               dd[j]++;
           }
       }
    }

    String newS="";
    for(int i=0;i<count.size();i++){
        newS+=count.get(i)+dd[i];
    }
```

str = newS;

```
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Integer data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) requires 32 bit or 4 bytes space whereas character array contains blocks of 16 bits or 2 bytes space.

You might want to create an another integer array to hold your count values as this is not possible in the same character array directly.

There is a workaround of storing [ASCII values](http://ascii.cl/) of corresponding count values as characters in the same array but it might lead to ambiguity if there are numbers present as part of your original character array.

Hence I would suggest you use a separate integer array.

Comment: Assuming the point was to replace any repeating character with the count, it can be done in a character array by iterating the array counting and replacing. It is a lot of array work, o be sure, but I do not believe you statement about holding count values is accurate.

Comment: If the array contains only characters, you can find ASCII values of their frequencies and append them as numeric characters, yes it is a lot of work. it might lead to ambiguity. But this is what OP wants to do. It is a workaround to get done but not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it using String, like you want to store 3 at 2nd position so do like this-

```
int n = 3;
String s = Integer.toString(n);
ch[1] = s.charAt(0); // ch[1] is representing 2nd position in aaabbc
```

Comment: How does this answer anything?

Comment: I converted 3 to string s and 3 will be at 0th index of s as a character and copied it to another  character. what is to tell in this ?

Comment: I can see what you're doing, but I don't see how it's remotely relevant to the question.

Comment: @shmosel sir, i gave answer for this part of question (Here is there any way to store integer value 3 in a character array).

Comment: I think @Utsav Kumar is facing problem in storing integer value in a character

Comment: That was not the problem at all. The question was how to convert "aaa" to "a3".